# Renderizar HTML en varios divs sin perder el formato

Tags: javascript, html5, angularjs, algoritmos

**Es posible renderizar el contenido de una página HTML en varios `divs` sin perder el formato/estructura de los elementos ???**

Estoy tratando de renderizar un contenido HTML en varios contenedores `div` (evitando romper el formato), los divs están separados unos de otros.

Por ejemplo, Teniendo en cuenta que en mi HTML tengo un `<table>` que es muy grande, mas grande que un contenedor `div`, en ese caso se podría renderizar dicha tabla en 2 `divs` sin perder su formato/estructura?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Cosas que he intentado:**

1.- Convertir el HTML a una imagen PNG, cortar la imagen PNG en trozos para que cada trozo vaya a un `div`. Pero el requerimiento que tengo indica que el texto debe ser seleccionable. Esta opción murió.

2.- He intentado tomar bloques de código (primer nivel en el DOM, dentro del `body`), calcular su altura,y si esa altura es menor a la altura del `div`, se lo renderiza dentro del div. Pero hay casos como: renderizar una tabla muy grande , más grande que la altura div, en este caso, no sé cómo hacerlo.

Todos mis intentos fueron utilizando AngularJs y Javascript puro. Cualquier consejo me sera de mucha ayuda.

Comment: Primero, deberías agregar lo que has intentado hasta el momento, de esta forma podremos ver más claramente por cual línea ibas y te podríamos ayudar mejor.

Comment: @RandallSandoval Lo hice, ahí esta las 2 cosas mas lógicas que he intentado hacer para resolver este problema.

Comment: y código? no has tratado con ningún código que podamos ver

Comment: Pondría mi código, pero en este caso me parece inútil porque no tengo errores ni dudas en el código. Lo que quiero saber es si es posible mi requerimiento, Si debo estudiar algo mas para lograrlo, o si mi requerimiento no es posible.

Comment: haz intentado usar bootstrap?

Comment: Gracias por responder @JackNavaRow. He intentado eso, pero como menciono en la pregunta, un requerimiento es que el texto sea seleccionable. al convertirlo a PNG o canvas el texto no sera seleccionable.

Comment: y por que no generas un pdf con los enlaces?, cual es tu problema principal la tabla?

Comment: Si. Tablas, Listas, parrafos o Cualquier elemento de DOM que su altura sea mas grande que el tamaño de un **div** contenedor. Lo ideal seria "dividir" la tabla(o cualquier otro elemento) y renderizarlo en 2 contenedores diferentes sin que esta pierda su estructura.

Comment: solucionalo con bootstrap!

Comment: @JackNavaRow Si utilizo Bootstrap, pero no entiendo como Bootstrap puede solucionar mi cuestión, creo que no me estoy dejando entender.

Comment: separa el table en dos row y cuando sea muy grande el automaticamente bajara

Comment: @JackNavaRow Te entiendo. Lamentablemente por temas de seguridad (requerimientos) no puedo modificar nada del HTML y en el HTML que me entregan puede o no tener atributos de bootstrap, ademas que los **divs** donde debo renderizar no estaran uno tras otro, estarán en distintas partes de DOM. Pfff las condiciones no son nada buenas jeje

Comment: Creo que se podría... Recuerdo que cuando estaba de moda utilizar `iframe` le decias que parte de la página querías cargar mediante **anclas**, creo que la función `load` de **JQuery** también hace lo mismo...

Comment: Si entiendo bien el problema lo puedes solucionar todo con css usando Flexbox y mediaquerys